# How to make use of movie events imported by imovie 09 from a DVR

Tags: mac, quicktime, imovie

I have imported about 100 clips of video from my DVR using imovie 09 and they are all saved under movie events folder, this is ok.

The problem is all the movie events files are not in standard formats, they are in some 'Apple Intermediate Format' only Quicktime and iMovie recoginize and play. My problem is I simply want to give my 100 clips of video to someone using PC and this intermediate format produced by imovie is not playable or convertable by anything I have found.

Now the only option for me seems to be creating a project in iMovie and drag all the clips into the project and then export these 100 clips into a single standard file, but iMovie doesn't even let me conveninent do that, I can only click at some clip, select all, drag into the project, and repeat for 100 more times, Is there a alternative way I can do so? (or use Quicktime player to convert video formats one by one).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format is pretty standard; you should be able to use any batch video conversion software (I strongly recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)) to convert them to whatever format your PC-using associate would like!